# wixtoolset custom Action script cannot retrieve windows registry to modify but can retrieve registry to read

Tags: c#, wix

I have a custom action script written in c# used in wixtoolset installer. Now the problem is when I try to retrieve a specified subkey with writable=false code works in line 2 but when I retrieve a specified subkey with writable=true I get null in line 5. So what can be the possible reasons for this issue and how can I fix it.

```
string path = "Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0"
if (Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path, false) != null)
{
    string szKeyName = "Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options";
    RegistryKey rkExcelXll = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(szKeyName, true);
    if (rkExcelXll != null)
    {
        session.Log("Exist");
    } else {
        session.Log("Do not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using RegistrySearch instead. It's built-in to the Windows Installer so no custom action required.